How to use advance javascript optimizations from angular cli >= v16 in webpack ( from @angular-devkit/build-optimizer)
We ve used @angular-devkit/build-optimizer link and @ngtools/webpack in our webpack build of angular app, until we bump script target from es5 to > es2020 and from typescript v4 to typescript v5, look like @angular-devkit/build-optimizer not compatible with typescript v5 and its not working, without this package our bundle size is increasing, because it properly prefix exported classes with PURE decorators.
example of build optimizer cli:
input TS v5 and target > ES5:
export let ViewHighlightLineageAction = class ViewHighlightLineageAction extends Action {
constructor( ... ) {
... 


and optimizer output:
let ViewHighlightLineageAction = /@PURE/ (() => {
**export let** ViewHighlightLineageAction = class ViewHighlightLineageAction extends Action {
constructor( ... ) {
...


export let inside function is issue.
So the question is that package saying and this functionality was folded into cli code, but i can not understand how to use it, what would be substitute for this package ?

Since the @angular-devkit/build-optimizer package is no longer compatible with TypeScript 5 and post-ES5 targets, and its functionality has been integrated into the Angular CLI, you'll have to drop it and use one of the options below:

Use the Angular CLI:
The simplest and most straightforward solution is to use the built-in Angular CLI build process (ng build). Angular CLI by default includes build optimizer functionality and performs various optimizations including adding @PURE annotations, tree-shaking and minimization. Switching to the Angular CLI to build your application will allow you to take advantage of these optimizations without additional configuration.

Customize your Webpack configuration:
If you need to keep a custom Webpack build process, you can customize your configuration to achieve similar optimizations:

Use the Angular Compiler plugin:
Make sure that you properly use the @ngtools/webpack Angular compiler plugin in AOT (Ahead-of-Time) mode. The plugin should perform the required optimizations when configured correctly.

Integrate Babel plugins:
Use Babel with babel-plugin-annotate-pure-calls plugin to add @PURE annotations to your code.





thanks for answer, we already started migration to CLI , this is for short term update,  Make sure that you properly use the @ngtools/webpack  - what that mean ? there is no options for opt in/out of optimizations
for babel - we tried - and no changes - i think i better setup small github repro for demo so we can discuss

I had problems connecting it, the plugin didn't work, while ide didn't give any errors. So it's important to check that it actually works and not just in the configuration
